# How to process dispatch async process in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Iam using new dispatch_queue for receiving Xmpp messages , while updating my tabbar count iam sending the notification. but it takes more time for updating my Uitabbar count. so i call the notification process alone with dispatch_queue_main(). But it makes my app freeze for some seconds while updating my tabbar count..

```
dispatch_queue_t exampleQueue = dispatch_queue_create( "xmpp_message", NULL );
dispatch_async(exampleQueue, ^{
// code for proceesing messages....

 dispatch_queue_t queue=dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [self sendNotification:msg];
});
});
```

anyone help with this, to process the notification process without freezing...

Answer (score 3):

The above syntax looks fine, and employs the appropriate technique for dispatching tasks to a background process, but then re-dispatching the UI update back to the main queue. So, you probably have to broaden your investigation. With that in mind, you might want to consider:

- Are you *absolutely sure* that no UI update related code slipped under the "code for processing messages" section? I've seen people report unexplained slow downs and then say something like "oh, I didn't know that included Core Graphics, too". I know this is unlikely, but check carefully.
- It's a silly question, but have you put `NSLog` statements in here, right at the start of both blocks? By doing this, you can confirm which queue is the culprit (if either), better understand the entry and exits of queues, etc. Not knowing your code, I would worry that the "code for processing messages" is taking too long.

  So you might:

  ```
  dispatch_queue_t exampleQueue = dispatch_queue_create( "xmpp_message", NULL );
  dispatch_async(exampleQueue, ^{

      NSLog(@"%s dispatched to xmpp_message", __FUNCTION__);

      // code for processing messages....

      dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
      dispatch_async(queue, ^{

          NSLog(@"%s     re-dispatched to main queue", __FUNCTION__);

          [self sendNotification:msg];

          NSLog(@"%s     finished dispatch to main queue", __FUNCTION__);
      });

      NSLog(@"%s finished dispatched to xmpp_message", __FUNCTION__);
  });

  // if not ARC or supporting iOS versions prior to 6.0, you should release the queue

  dispatch_release(exampleQueue);
  ```
- You might also also want to make sure that you're not having problems resulting from the serial nature of custom queues. Is the serial nature required, or can you contemplate concurrent queues?

  So try:

  ```
  dispatch_queue_t exampleQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0); // or in  recent versions of iOS, you can use dispatch_queue_create( "xmpp_message", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT );
  dispatch_async(exampleQueue, ^{

      NSLog(@"%s dispatched to xmpp_message", __FUNCTION__);

      // code for processing messages....

      dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
      dispatch_async(queue, ^{

          NSLog(@"%s re-dispatched to main queue", __FUNCTION__);

          [self sendNotification:msg];
      });
  });
  ```
- You might, finally, want to try run app with the "Time Profiler" tool in [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). See the WWDC 2012 session on [Building Concurrent User Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211) for a demonstration of how you can use that tool.

Those are the only ideas that leap out at me.

Comment: I have tried the second code in the beginning, the same slow down happens... When i switch the global queue to the main queue, small freezes takes place while updating the uitabbar count.. How to control the freezes, if i doesnt switch to main queue, no freeze happens but tabbarcount takes more time to change... hope u can help me.. with this.....

Comment: Does there is a any other method apart from main queue to make the UItabbar count change quickly without freezing...

Comment: @RahulNair So, is the "re-dispatched" message showing up quickly, and the tab bar change slowly? Or does the "re-dispatched" `NSLog` message show up slowly, too?

Comment: In answer to your question, I find that tab bar updates happen nearly instantaneously, so if you're experiencing some delay, I assume it's related to your queues.