# Dispatch_sync from the main thread using the main thread's queue useless?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading

I just want to confirm my reasoning that doing a dispatch_sync from the UI thread(main thread) using the main queue is utterly useless.

To add to that, async would be just as useless but with the illusion that it is useful because it doesn't block.

Let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dispatch_sync` to the same queue is not only useless, but it will lock your app. `dispatch_sync` says "dispatch something, but don't proceed on this queue until the other queue responds". That obviously can't happen if the "other" queue (that we're waiting for it to complete the dispatched block) is the same one as "this" queue (which is blocked until that other queue responds). Your app will freeze, waiting for itself!

On the other hand, `dispatch_async` to the same queue you're currently on is not generally a very useful construction, but at least it won't freeze. I've seen some awkward code that used `dispatch_async` to itself as a way of saying "as soon as I finish some series of actions, I then want to do something else". I've rarely seen this dispatching asynchronously to itself in situations where it couldn't be done more elegantly another way, but I have seen it.

Comment: So if I create my own queue, tasks that goes on that queue is going to be done on a different thread?

Comment: @mskw Yes, that's correct. The `dispatch` methods are most useful for submitting a block of code to a separate queue. A very typical pattern is when you're doing something that's very slow, you might `dispatch` that to a queue of your own creation (or to one of the `dispatch_get_global_queue` queues), and when that needs up then update the UI (which always must be done on the main queue), you'll then `dispatch_async` the UI updates back to the main queue (`dispatch_get_main_queue()`) from within the block of code you dispatched to that background queue.

Comment: See [how to process dispatch async process in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624734/how-to-process-dispatch-async-process-in-background/13625739#13625739) for an example of that pattern.

Comment: Thats exactly the answer i was looking for!  The dispatch_async from within the separate queue to update the UI. THANKS

Comment: Dispatch_async from the main thread to the main thread has occasionally been useful to me for workarounds of some UIKit quirks (there's an answer somewhere by me that I can't find about UIAppearance and segmented controls)